# Manipulating the Scheme evaluator

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to manipulate the Scheme evaluator and write a `make-unbound!` procedure that unbinds a variable from the environment:

```
(define (make-unbound! var env)
  (let ((frame (first-frame env)))
      (define (scan vars vals)
        (let ((new-frame 
                (make-frame 
                  (zip 
                    (filter (lambda (x) (not (eq? x (car vars)))) vars)
                    (filter (lambda (x) (not (eq? x (car vals)))) vals))
                  env)))
        (cond ((null? vars) 
               (display '(No frame to unbind)))
              ((eq? var (car vars))
               (set-car! vars new-frame)) ; the problem seems to be here
              (else (scan (cdr vars) (cdr vals))))))
      (scan (frame-variables frame)
            (frame-values frame))))
```

The problem seems to be with where I'm setting the *car* of the variable. But I'm not sure what it should be changing to....

Comment: Racket doesn't have `first-frame`, `make-frame`, `frame-variables`, and `frame-values`. Where do these procedures come from?

Comment: there is a lot of other coding that goes with this, but the basic idea is that I'm trying to create a procedure that unbinds a variable from an environment.  I tried to create a new frame that has all the variables except for the one that it's unbinding, and then set the car of the variable to the new frame, but that doesn't work.  I'm just not sure what I'm supposed to do with the new frame after I've created it...

Answer (score 1):

This looks like exercise 4.13 of SICP. The `make-unbound!` special form can be evaluated like this using Racket:

```
(define (remove-association! key lst)
  (define (loop prev l)
    (cond ((null? l) lst)
          ((equal? (mcar (mcar l)) key)
           (set-mcdr! prev (mcdr l))
           lst)
          (else (loop l (mcdr l)))))
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ((eq? (mcar (mcar lst)) key) (mcdr lst))
        (else (loop lst (mcdr lst)))))

(define (unbind-variable! var env)
  (define (env-loop env)
    (define (scan bindings)
      (cond ((massq var bindings)
             (set-mcar! env (remove-association! var bindings)))
            (else (env-loop (enclosing-environment env)))))
    (unless (eq? env the-empty-environment)
      (scan (first-frame env))))
  (env-loop env))

(define (unbound-variable exp)
  (cadr exp))

(define (eval-make-unbound! exp env)
  (unbind-variable! (unbound-variable exp)
                    env))
```

It removes the first binding that finds with the given symbol, be it in the current frame or any of its enclosing environments. If the symbol was unbound in the first place, it does nothing. I chose to implement the unbind operation in this fashion so that the (possible) bindings in enclosing environments are kept intact.

Don't forget to specify in the `eval` procedure that the special form `make-unbound!` is to be evaluated using the `eval-make-unbound` procedure.

Also, be warned that I made my implementation using Racket's mutable pairs library, so the procedure names I'm using sometimes have an extra `m` somewhere in their names, meaning: they're defined for *mutable* pairs. For example: `mcar, mcdr, set-mcar!, set-mcdr!, massq`. If any of the previous procedures is not found, simply remove the `m` from the name and try again.

Comment: Thanks! Unless isn't defined in my scheme, how do I define it?

Comment: `(unless <condition> <body>)` is shorthand for `(if (not <condition>) (begin <body>))`

Comment: Also, it's possible that in the Scheme language you're using `mcar, mcdr, set-mcar!, set-mcdr!` are called `car, cdr, set-car!, set-cdr!`

Comment: Right. That's like `assq`, but for mutable lists of mutable pairs. The thing is, I made my implementation using Racket's mutable pairs library, so the procedure names I'm using sometimes have an extra `m` in front of their names, meaning: mutable.